# How did Hagrid get with Voldemort and the Death Eaters?

Tags: harry-potter

In the movie, we don’t see Hagrid until he’s being held captive by Voldemort’s Death Eaters in the Forbidden Forest. How did he get caught by the Death Eaters ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In the book, Hagrid, Grawp (his giant half-brother), and Fang
>   (Hagrid’s dog) show up at the castle to fight before Harry finds the
>   diadem. He gets caught up in a swarm of spiders retreating to the
>   Forbidden Forest, which must be where the Death Eaters grab him.
>   Capturing him so he’ll be there to carry Harry Potter’s dead body back
>   to the castle — that’s some planning!

http://popwatch.ew.com/2011/07/19/harry-potter-deathly-hallows-part-2-burning-questions/

Comment: Not quite sure if joke or not, so please bear with me:). Hagrid carrying Harry was not a plan. It actually stroke Voldemort's mind at the last moment. For lack of room see third quote in [Mooz's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56807/in-deathly-hallows-why-do-voldemort-co-just-tie-hagrid-up-why-not-kill-him/56814#56814).

Comment: just because it wasn't part of Voldemort's plan, doesn't mean Hagrid's being there was any less convenient for the plot. I do like Mooz's answer though.

Answer (score 4):

In the book, Hagrid fled the school after defying the Snape/Carrow administration by hosting a party in support of Harry.
Between his flight and the Battle of Hogwarts, Hagrid was hiding in a mountain cave:

> “Get right out of Hogsmeade, up into the mountains, and you’ll be able
> to Disapparate there. Might see Hagrid. He’s been hiding in a cave up
> there with Grawp ever since they tried to arrest him.”
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Hagrid came back to fight with the defenders of Hogwarts, and was later carried off by the descendents of his Acromantula friend Aragog.

> “HAGRID, COME BACK!” But he was not even halfway to Hagrid when he saw
> it happen: Hagrid vanished amongst the spiders, and with a great
> scurrying, a foul swarming movement, they retreated under the
> onslaught of spells, Hagrid buried in their midst.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Since the spiders retreated, they must have gone back to the forest, which was their home. Since Voldemort and his forces had also set up camp in the forest, presumably they saw this as an excellent opportunity to humiliate a hated opponent.